# Is it possible to have a picture object in the python code without reading from file?

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter

reading picture from a directory every time is how normal code will do,
but is that possible that we can save the picture object at the first time we open it
then we copy the picture object and save in our code so that we don't need to read from file next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the base64 module to encode the image data in base64. You can then pass the encoded data to `PhotoImage` with the `data` parameter.

```
import tkinter as tk

image_data = """
    R0lGODlhGAAYAPZvAAIaLgwmOwcnQQcoQBMxSBc4VBQ6Vhk7VRY9WhY+XSI4RxJC
    ZRRCZi9KYSFNbzJUbSJOcCZVeiZUeyBWfy1Zei5afB1Wgh1XgyFXgDpjgSVjkyZl
    liZnmCxrmixsmjZtlSptoCpuoSxxqCxzqjh1oTV3qDR4qD5/rjV8tDV+tUFlgUZp
    hFNwhVVyh0ZzlUh7nnB8hUF8pkJ8pkx+oTuBuFmBn3SEkHeOn3mNnUeBqUiBqUqD
    q1CBpFKCpVuDoVyEokeGs0eHs0aKvkaMvlGOuGqKom+Pp3yUpziEwTiFwz2KxT+K
    xE6VylKUw1qaxV6fx0CQ0E+b1lCd1l6h0Wiq1Wyu12Wp22aq3FOi4F2s5WCt5W64
    7XW24Xu743u/6omfsZymroqhso6jtJynsJ2psaS1w6S2xIvH7YvI7d/h5ODi5eDk
    5+Dm6uLn7OPo7QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH+SUNvcHlyaWdodCBJTkNPUlMgR21iSCAod3d3Lmljb25l
    eHBlcmllbmNlLmNvbSkgLSBVbmxpY2Vuc2VkIHByZXZpZXcgaW1hZ2UAIfkEBQAA
    bwAsAAAAABgAGAAAB9eAb4KDhIWGh4iJiouMjY6PiGkwCgAACjBqj2ABBSw3Ny0H
    AWONYwIqYmFfX2FiKwNki2kEFEZFRba3RhUEa4o2Cy41NT/FPsMuDDaKDRYfLzM8
    PT0zMy8fFw2KBRoeJDI6Ojs5MSQdGwaKCCAmJ0FE8ERAJyUhCYoPIjRDTU5PT06a
    CKEx4oEiHBuWMJlCpUoVKlOYKOFwQxEbB0ikXOHSpQsXK1GSQGizyIwFKFq8oDnj
    JQsUDGYalYmAYsqWLVhSSIjpqM2RDBMuZDjiBpLRo0iTKjUaCAA7
"""

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data)
label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of label with image on it]